# Count number of days between 2 dates in JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I need to count the number of days between 2 dates in JPA.

For example :

```
CriteriaBuilder.construct(
  MyCustomBean.class
  myBean.get(MyBean_.beginDate), //Expression<Date>
  myBean.get(MyBean_.endDate), //Expression<Date>
  myDiffExpr(myBean) //How to write this expression from the 2 Expression<Date>?
);
```

So far, I tried :

1. `CriteriaBuilder.diff()`. but it does not compile because this method expects some `N extends Number` and the `Date` does not extend `Number`.
2. I tried to extend the `PostgreSQL82Dialect` (as my target database is PostgreSQL) :

   ```
   public class MyDialect extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {

     public MyDialect() {
       super();
       registerFunction("datediff", 
       //In PostgreSQL, date2 - date1 returns the number of days between them.
       new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.LONG, " (?2 - ?1) "));
     }
   }
   ```

This compiles and the request succeeds but the returned result is not consistent (78 days between today and tomorrow).

How would you do this?

Comment: How try with *#1* `date.getTime()` as it is `Long`, and another way is to try with native sql query in JPA?

Comment: @ANyarThar DO you havge a way to get this `Expression<Long>` (dateTime) from the `Expression<Date>`?

Comment: My suggestion is like the answer below.

Comment: Please write an example query/statement you want to use. I'm still not sure what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a solution with JPQL to perform queries like `SELECT p FROM Period p WHERE datediff(p.to, p.from) > 10`.

I'm afraid there is no such functionality in JPQL so I recommend using native SQL. Your idea if extending Dialect with Hibernate's `SQLFunctionTemplate` was very clever. I'd rather change it to use `DATE_PART('day', end - start)` as this is the way to achieve days difference between dates with PostgreSQL.

You might also define your function [in PostgreSQL and using it with criteria `function()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14137479/how-to-use-a-native-db-operator-postgres-with-jpa-criteria-builder).

```
'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "datediff"(TIMESTAMP,TIMESTAMP) RETURNS integer AS \'DATE_PART('day', $1 - $2);\' LANGUAGE sql;'

cb.function("datediff", Integer.class, end, start);
```

Comment: I tried but as `end - start` is considered as an Integer by Postgres, the corresponding function does not work. My problem might not come from the template but maybe from the way I use it. I am still investigating.

Comment: `end - start` in PostgreSQL should produce INTERVAL type. I don't think there is corresponding Java type.

Comment: The fact that JPA can't even subtract dates says a lot about how useful it is in the real world.

Comment: I wouldn't go that far. JPQL, which is a query language of JPA cannot do it. But JPA? Sure can. Just select two dates so you can have it as Java objects, and you can subtract it many different ways.

Comment: @zbigniewTomczak I finally found that the problem came from the `(?2 - ?1)` part. I opened a new question about it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037380/sqlfunctiontemplate-does-not-apply-the-order-of-the-query-parameter

Answer (score 2):

JPA 2.1 provides for use of "FUNCTION(funcName, args)" in JPQL statements. That allows such handling.

Comment: And what would be the Oracle function to call for date subtraction?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that the problem comes from the fact that the order of the parameters is not the one I expected :

```
/*
 *(?2 - ?1) is actually equivalent to (? - ?).
 * Hence, when I expect it to evaluate (date2 - date1), 
 * it will actually be evaluated to (date1 - date2)
 */
new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.LONG, " (?2 - ?1) "));
```

I opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25037380/sqlfunctiontemplate-does-not-apply-the-order-of-the-query-parameters) in order to know if this behavior is a bug or a feature :

Comment: The implementation in Hibernate looks good to me. I didn't change from ver 3.3.0. Have you confirmed this in your logs? Are you sure that is not a "thing" with transforming PostgreSQL Interval type to Java long type?

Comment: @zbigniewTomczak I found this by modifying the postgres configuration file in order to make it log the full request (with parameters values). I use Hibernate 4.3.1.Final. I do not use PostgreSQL intervals. I give 2 `Expression<Date>` and PostgreSQL returns an integer which represents the number of days between the dates. I changed `?2 - ?1` to `-?1 + ?2` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) CriteriaBuilder.diff(). but it does not compile because this method expects some N extends Number and the Date does not extend Number.

Try to use no of mili seconds for each date as shown below.

```
Date date = new Date()//use your required date
long millisecond = date.getTime();//Returns no of mili seconds from 1 Jan, 1970 GMT
```

Long in Number in java and according to autoboxing you can use this. May be this can help.

Comment: My dates are acutally `Expression<Date>`. How is it possible to extract the dateTime of it? (For example, building an `Expression<Long>` that I could use with `CriteriaBuilder.diff` ? I edited the question to make it clearer.