# SQLFunctionTemplate does not apply the order of the query parameters

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I reduced the problem to this simple template :

```
//I extend the PostgreSQL dialect because I need a non-standard feature.
public class MyDialect extends PostgreSQL82Dialect {

  public MyDialect() {
    //With PostgreSQL, "date2 - date1" returns the number of days between the 2 given dates.
    registerFunction("date_diff", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.LONG, " ((?2) - (?1)) "));
  }
}
```

In this request, I noticed that Hibernate does not care about the number after `?` in `((?2) - (?1))`

Hence, If i use :

```
Expression<Date> date1 = ...
Expression<Date> date2 = ...
em.getCriteriaBuilder().function("date_diff", Integer.class, date1, date2);
```

the call will return the result of `(date1 - date2)` but I had expected `(date2 - date1)`.

Is it a bug or a feature? What is the point of giving a number to the parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies with parameter binding. I had a similar issue when trying to register a function for DATE_ADD with SQL Server. Here was my method call:

```
registerFunction("addminutes", new TestSqlFunctionTemplate(TimeMillisType.INSTANCE, "DATEADD(MINUTE, ?2, ?1)"));
```

After digging through the [source code for TemplateRenderer](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-core/5.0.0.Beta1/org/hibernate/dialect/function/TemplateRenderer.java#TemplateRenderer) I found the issue lies with how the SQL string is rendered. The render function is passed a list of the arguments to send, but since the parameters are bound it is sent a List of "?" Strings that indicate the bound parameter. The output for the render function when using a query with bound parameters in my example was:

```
DATEADD(MINUTE, ?, ?)
```

Which gives no indication of the order. I'm looking for an alternate solution, but I haven't come across anything as of yet.