# Is there a function to subtract dates in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, date, datetime

I know in Oracle I can directly subtract two date columns and check how many days are between them:

```
 SELECT * FROM VOYAGE WHERE endDate - beginDate > 30
```

But, is there a built-in Oracle function that does exactly the same? Just like MySQL's DATEDIFF seems to do:

```
 SELECT * FROM VOYAGE WHERE DATEDIFF(endDate,beginDate) > 30
```

I need this as a function to overcome a shortcomming in the ORM framework I'm using.

Creating a function is not an option. It would have to really  be builtin.

Comment: Could you explain why you need to call a function? Maybe there is a workaround for that ORM limitation to get it to work with Oracle's built in date arithmetic.

Comment: btw,  if you want to get the exact integer difference like `DATEDIFF(day,endDate,beginDate)`, then you need `trunc(endDate) - trunc(beginDate)` . Do you know  ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan,  I don't mind, actually. In my specif case, the columns are already truncated dates (all at midnight).

Comment: @MickMnemonic The ORM is plain Java JPA. The problem is discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991581/count-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-jpa

Comment: Ok, thanks. So, you could do this is native SQL through JPA also. Is that out of the question?

Comment: Not exactly *number of days*, but - if it helps, see the `months_between` function which returns number of *months* between two dates. I don't know of any function in Oracle that does what you asked.

Comment: @MickMnemonic, my real-world query will actually include many other dynamic predicates. So, native SQL - or even jpql - unfortunately is not an option to me.

Comment: @Littlefoot yes, I'm actually looking for a `days_between` kind of function.

Comment: Well, there's none. Unless you write your own function, of course. Or, open a Service Request on MOS and ask Oracle to include such a function into one of its future releases. Don't hold your breath.

Comment: If anyone can provide a reliable positive reference to @Littlefoot claim, I would accept as an answer.

Comment: Using something like `ROUND(MONTHS_BETWEEN(endDate, beginDate) * (365/12)) > 30` almost works. There's a rounding error (that you see with longer date intervals) that you might be able to get rid of by modifying the normalization constant or the rounding function.

Comment: @MickMnemonic No good. Leap years.

Comment: A "reliable positive reference" is called "Oracle documentation". Feel free to research it, here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/

Comment: @Littlefoot, "Feel free to research it" is a negative reference. Sorry.

Comment: This seems like an X-Y question: You're trying to use a built-in function in Oracle that doesn't exist, just because you need it for dynamic queries in JPA. I think you should be asking how to get those queries working instead. The Criteria API supports having part of the query in native SQL, so I don't really understand why the function would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

there is none in oracle built in function for days between.

there is **months_between**

You can write your own function if you want

Comment: That's a strong claim. Do you have a reference?

Answer (score 0):

If you are explicitly needing a function that takes two date parameters and returns a number of days, then you will have to write your own.
As the other answer indicates, the only built-in standard function that takes in two dates and returns a number is MONTHS_BETWEEN

```
select package_name, object_name, overload, count(*), 
       listagg(argument_name||' '||data_type||' '||in_out,';') 
                  within group (order by position) args
from all_arguments
where package_name = 'STANDARD'
and owner = 'SYS'
group by package_name, object_name, overload
having 1=max(case when position = 0 and in_out = 'OUT' 
                   and data_type = 'NUMBER' then 1 end)
and 2 = sum(case when data_type = 'DATE' and in_out = 'IN' then 1 end)
and count(*) = 3;
```