# Spring Data JPA Find Closest Date

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a table that stores milestones (id, description, date) and given some event date, I would like to find the milestone that occurred closest to that date.

I am using Spring Data JPA and I cannot seem to figure out how to do it. Based on the available [functions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation), there does not seem to be anything natively available to find the closest date. At the moment the best idea I have come up with is to use raw sql something along the lines of

```
select id, description, date, date-'2021-05-18' as datediff from milestones order by datediff desc limit 1
```

I would then have a function on my repo like

```
 @Query("select id, description, date, date - :eventDate as datediff from milestones order by datediff desc limit 1")
    List<Milestones> findClosest(Date eventDate );
```

My main concern with this approach is that I have to rely on a DBMS specific function to perform the date difference and select only the first result. Since this seems like a common problem I am wondering if there are any better an DBMS agnostic alternatives available.

Notes

- Closest date can be before or after the event date
- I am using postgres but ideally a solution should work for any DBMS

Answer (score 0):

I think that you will find that there is no method for finding a "closest" date in any of the well-known relational databases.

However, you might be able to do something like what you are currently doing, but using JPA-compliant syntax instead of database-specific syntax.

See [Count number of days between 2 dates in JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24991581/count-number-of-days-between-2-dates-in-jpa) for some ideas.